# Read CSV data using Microsoft text driver

Tags: csv, text, driver

I want to read data from a CSV file using microsoft text driver. Can somebody give me the code or post some links.

Thanks.

Comment: Click on the up arrow and √ sign. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow one of these links that would help:

[Microsoft MSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx)N,
[EggHead Cafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020108.asp) or
[Microsft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187670).